# Program works fine in the compiler (Eclipse), but when I export it, it doesn't work

Tags: java, eclipse

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Frame");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JButton button = new JButton("Button");
        
        panel.setBounds(0,0,300,300);
        panel.setLayout(null);
        button.setBounds(120,140,60,20);
        
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                panel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            }   
        });
        
        frame.setSize(300,300);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        panel.add(button);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

So this is my code. It works perfectly until I export it as a Runnable JAR file. I'm using Eclipse as IDE and I'm on the Windows 10. When I right-click on the project and click export, I choose Runnable JAR file as an option. After that, I choose right Main class and location where I want to save my file. This is where the problem starts: When I'm choosing **Library Handling** option, I have 3 options.

1. Extract required libraries into generated JAR
2. Package required libraries into generated JAR
3. Copy required libraries into a sub-folder next to the generated JAR

And so, when I choose the option 1), this is the error message that I get: **Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again**, and then, it's followed by: **A Java Exception has occurred**. After that, it just closes.

When I choose the second and third option, I don't get any error message while running it, but my cursor looks like it's loading something for 1 second and that's it.

**Note that this code works in Eclipse, and the problem only occurs when I export the program.**

**Also, this happens with every program that I try to export.**

So, if you have any advice or the solution for this problem, please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your example has no required libraries. It sounds like you don't have your os setup to handle jar files correctly. What happens if you use a terminal/command prompt and run java -jar your-jar-file.jar

Comment: This message appears: Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Main has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 59.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

Comment: It sounds like your os is pointing to an outdated JDK. What do you get when you run `java -version` and what JDK is eclipse using?

Comment: Oh, thank you so much, when I read that message I googled it and I got it. Thank you so much!